# Отображение вложенного запроса в списке выбираемых полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Пример:

таблица `goods` с полями `id`, `price`, `good`.

Нужно вывести, используя вложенный запрос, поля price, good

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
        `price`
    FROM
        `goods`
) AS `цена`,
(
    SELECT
        `good`
    FROM
        `goods`
) AS `товар`
```

*Возвращает NULL*

Если задать так

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT
        `price`
    FROM
        `goods`
    WHERE `id`=1
) AS `цена`,
(
    SELECT
        `good`
    FROM
        `goods`
    WHERE `id`=1
) AS `товар`
```

*Запрос отобразится*

***Прошу Вас помочь составить sql запрос.***

Comment: Вообще, крайне непонятна сама постановка и смысл задачи. В данном случае незачем выбирать данные с помощью вложенного запроса да ещё с проверкой условия. Всё это можно сделать одним простым запросом.

Answer (score 1):

судя по всему, вы хотите получить в результате несколько строк.

но, во-первых, `select` без `from` всегда возвращает только одну строку.

а во-вторых, если вместо одного из столбцов в запросе используется вложенный запрос, то этот вложенный запрос должен возвращать ровно одну строку с ровно одним столбцом.